# Is watching people drink wine or eat pork meat haram?(Mukbang)

Tags: halal-haram, pork

Assalamu alaikum, I was wondering is watching videos of people eating pork meat haram? Or drinking wine?
I've seen some people say that whatever is haram to do is haram to look at, So if im just watching people eat pork meat for example asmr videos is it haram?
Also please another question,
Is it also haram to watch non muslim chefs cooking chicken or meat when i dont know if they slaughtered it in islamic way?

Comment: I don't think so. If you see a video of a drunken driver getting off the road, killing pedestrians, would you be incited to do the same or be rather alarmed and appalled *not* to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You would be supporting those people who make videos based on sin so it's assumed that it's haram to support them:

“Help you one another in virtue, righteousness and piety; but do not help one another in sin and transgression. And fear Allah. Verily, Allah is Severe in punishment”
-Surah Al-Ma’idah verse 2